# refresh contents of div without id

Tags: javascript, jquery, database-connection

I am trying to add a refresh button to a table.  I currently am using.

```
var $target = $(this).parent().parent().next('.box');
$target.load("$site #" +$target.prop("nodeName");
```

There are many .box on the page.  When I use the .load() is there a way I can reference the specific .box maybe by location in the DOM?

Also, is there a way to delay the table loading tell the update in the database has finished?  I handle the update to the database before i load the content, but it still seems to load as if the database update had not happened, and a refresh is required.

Thank you

Comment: If you always target the same .box why not just assign it an ID and target that instead?

Comment: I want the code to be reusable.  I have three box's on my page I would like to be able to refresh separately. I need my $(a#refresh-btn).click... to work for the box that the link is on.

Comment: Do you have a separate refresh button for each box in order to refresh them separately? Can you post some of the HTML structure for this?

Comment: I would like the refresh button to be linked to the current box.  It would be the same button for each box but a different instances(?) of the button http://jsfiddle.net/jZX3p/

Answer (score 0):

You can reorganize the Html a little bit, for example wrapping the .box-content inside the .refresh div

```
<section class="col col-lg-8">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header">
                <h2> <i class="fa fa-user"></i><span class="break"></span>Recently Added</h2>

            <div class="box-icon"><a class="btn-minimize" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>

            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- Box Header -->
        <div class="box-icon"><a class="btn-reload" href="#">reload<i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a>


        <div class="box-content">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Date registered</th>
                        <th>Role</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
   </div>
```

then `var $target = $(this).parent().parent().next('.box-content');` can be changed to something like:

```
var $target = $(this).find('.box-content');
```

Otherwise the .parent.parent style you have now should work as long as the HTML maintains that layout for each section; You are referencing it's location in the DOM using the parent.parent.next code since you know that will be the location of the proper box-content div.

Edit: To elaborate on why find will work with your html structure .find and the similar .children elements only look at descendant elements: from http://api.jquery.com/find/

Based on the sample Html you showed me:

```
<.box>
    <box descendant>
        <descendant element>
    </box descendant>
    <box descendant2>
    </box descendant2>
</box>
<.box>
    <box descendant>
        <descendant element>
    </box descendant>
    <box descendant2>
    </box descendant2>
</box>
```

Doing:

```
 $(.box).click(function(){
    $(this).find(descendant element)
});
```

Will always get the correct element since .find will stay within the parent element

Comment: There will be several box-contents.  would find have an issue in picking the correct one?   This still isn't explaining how I can $target.load(mysite + 'correct box-content')